# How can I get this values from a loop function?

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop

The output should be:

1 2 4 8 16

2 6 18 54 162

3 12 48 192 768

4 20 100 500 2500

5 30 180 1080 6480

6 42 294 2058 14406

I am currently stuck with my code:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int size = 6; 
    
        for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
        {
            int num = i; 
        
            if(num == 1) {
              for (int j = 1; j < size; j++)
              {
                   Console.Write(num + " "); 

                   num *= 2; 
               }
          
               Console.WriteLine();
               }else{
               int num2 = 2;
        
               for (int j = 1; j < size; j++)
               {

               Console.Write(num2 + " "); 
              num2 *= 3;
          }       
           Console.WriteLine();
          }

       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code and the expected results formula should be something like `num *= i+1`, so you can try just inner loop without any `if`:

```cs
int size = 6;

for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
{
    int num = i;
    for (int j = 1; j < size; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(num + " ");
        num *= i + 1;
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: That was way shorter, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This one would work too, using `Math.Pow`

```
int size = 6;
for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(i * Math.Pow(i + 1, j));
        Console.Write(" ");
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `for` loop into this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
    {
        int num = i; 
    
        if(num == 1) {
          for (int j = 1; j < size; j++)
          {
               Console.Write(num + " "); 

               num *= 2; 
           }
      
           Console.WriteLine();
           }else{
           int num2 = i;
    
           for (int j = 1; j < size; j++)
           {

           Console.Write(num2 + " "); 
          num2 *= i+1;
      }       
       Console.WriteLine();
      }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int size = 6; 
    
        for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
        {
            int num = i; 
        
            
            if(num == 1) {
              Console.WriteLine();
              for (int j = 1; j < size; j++)
              {
                   Console.Write(num + " "); 

                   num *= 2; 
               }
          
               Console.WriteLine();
            }else{
               int num2 = i;
               for (int j = 1; j < size; j++)
               {

                Console.Write(num2 + " "); 
                num2 *= i+1;
               }       
               Console.WriteLine();
          }

       }
    }
```